# Spring batch do not deallocate memory (out of memory problem)

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch massive loading that reading from a huge xml file (2GB), processing and write into DB oracle with hibernate persist query. I used chunk of 100 elements for this.
The problem is that when I running this batch on server the memory allocation increase until the process is killed for 'out of memory' (i used top command on server and the process comes to use 20Gb memory!)..i think that, for some reason, spring not deallocate memory after ending the chunk elements.
Can you help me to understand what happened?

Comment: Do you use the `HibernateItemWriter`? If yes, then are you sure the `clearSession` parameter is not set to false? Please share your reader/writer config to be able to see where the memory leak could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `JAXB`/`JAXB2` to unmarshal the xml data, by any chance? If so, the problem could be related to the initialization of the `JAXBContext` in your method, instead of initializing it once in your application. Initializing the `JAXBContext` is an expensive operation and a frequent cause of memory leaks. More info related to this issue can be found [here](http://javaintherealworld.blogspot.com/2013/10/jaxbcontext-memory-leak.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Are you using JAXB/JAXB2 to unmarshal the xml data, by any chance? If so, the problem could be related to the initialization of the JAXBContext in your method, instead of initializing it once in your application. Initializing the JAXBContext is an expensive operation and a frequent cause of memory leaks. More info related to this issue can be found here.

I'm using Stax as follow:

```
public class ClassReader<T> extends StaxEventItemReader<T> {

    public MyClassReader(Class<T> t) {
        super();
        XStreamMarshaller unmarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();

        HashMap<String, Object> aliases = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        aliases.put("RECORD", t);
        unmarshaller.setAliases(aliases);

        this.setFragmentRootElementName("RECORD");

        this.setUnmarshaller(unmarshaller);
    }
}
```

I don't think this is the problem..